# pandas multiple column replace

Tags: python, pandas

I have `df` as given below which I am splitting column wise.

```
>>> df 
           ID      Started
0           NaN  20.06.2017  13:19:04
1           NaN  10.04.2018  04:48:32
2     WBTS-1509  06.11.2017  10:28:14
3     WBTS-1509  03.03.2018  10:12:29
4     WBTS-1117  07.03.2018  17:04:28
df['Started'].apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[0])
df['ID'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[1])
```

I would like to set  3 list variables

```
col_names = ['ID' , 'Started']
splitby = ['-' , ':']
index_after_split = [1 , 0]
```

do splitting using one line (avoiding loop)  using `inplace = True`.

Please help me do same.

Thanks

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: want to split values of 'ID' by "-" and retain index 1  and split values of 'Started" by ":" and retain index 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think loop is necessary here with [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and indexing by `str[]`:

```
for a,b,c, in zip(col_names, splitby, index_after_split):
    df[a] = df[a].str.split(b).str[c]
print (df)
     ID        Started
0   NaN  20.06.2017 13
1   NaN  10.04.2018 04
2  1509  06.11.2017 10
3  1509  03.03.2018 10
4  1117  07.03.2018 17
```